# Combinations of lists

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

I have a doubt about combinations of lists:

I imagine that I read a variable N from input (user sets this variable)

Then I have the following list:

```
val listExample = List("N1", "N2", "N4", "N5")
```

If variable **N** is **3** then my output would be the possible combinations (without repeating) of **listExample** with 3 elements like this:

```
List("N1", "N2", "N4")
List("N1", "N2", "N5")
List("N1", "N4", "N5")
List("N2", "N4", "N5")
```

If variable **N** is **2** then my output would be the possible combinations (without repeating) of **listExample** with 2 elements like this:

```
List("N1", "N2")
List("N1", "N4")
List("N1", "N5")
List("N2", "N4")
List("N2", "N5")
List("N4", "N5")
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @userunknown yes my bad, edited with the right value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
listExample.combinations(n).toList
```